# TikZ: \foreach within Bracketed Arguments

Tags: tikz-pgf, optional-arguments, decorations

I am trying to efficiently draw two concentric ellipses with four equally spaced dots at the cardinal directions using Ti*k*Z. Currently, I have the following code which generates the following image.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \s in {1,0.3} {
        \draw [blue,thick,scale=\s,decoration={markings,
            mark=at position 0    with {\fill circle (2pt);},
            mark=at position 0.25 with {\fill circle (2pt);},
            mark=at position 0.5  with {\fill circle (2pt);},
            mark=at position 0.75 with {\fill circle (2pt);}
        },postaction={decorate}] ellipse (2cm and 1.4cm);
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I figured out that a `\foreach` loop could be used to reduce hassle and draw both ellipses at the same time. However, I was wondering if it's possible to do something similar for the four `mark` arguments since the only thing that changes between them is the `position` value.

I have tried `\foreach` as follows, but it does not seem to work.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \s in {1,0.3} {
        \draw [blue,thick,scale=\s,decoration={markings,
            \foreach \x in {0,0.25,0.5,0.75} {
                mark=at position \x with {\fill circle (2pt);}
            }
        },postaction={decorate}] ellipse (2cm and 1.4cm);
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Is there a way to make such a thing work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutely. This is what the `/.list` key is for. You only need to define a style that takes the position as an argument, `cmark` in the example below, and can apply it on the list of positions with `cmark/.list={0,0.25,0.5,0.75}`. It understands everything `\foreach` would understand, so `cmark/.list={0,0.25,...,0.75}` will also work (but not really buy us much in this very case).

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[cmark/.style={decoration={markings,
              mark=at position #1 with {\fill circle (2pt);}
            },postaction={decorate}}]
    \foreach \s in {1,0.3} {
      \draw [blue,thick,scale=\s,cmark/.list={0,0.25,0.5,0.75}] ellipse (2cm and 1.4cm);
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

No need to reinvent the wheel, the marking library allows you to loop natively with the syntax described on page 639 of the 3.1.4b manual, I quote:

> /pgf/decoration/mark=betweenpositions < start pos > and < end pos >
>   step  with < code > (no default)

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \s in {1,0.3} {
        \draw [blue,thick,scale=\s,decoration={markings,
         mark= between positions 0 and .9 step 0.25
         with {\fill circle (2pt);}
        },postaction={decorate}] 
        ellipse (2cm and 1.4cm);
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: This has various limitations. For instance, it only allows one step size.

Comment: I did end up using this solution in my particular case. However, since the other answer will likely be more useful to other people with the same problem, I decided to accept it. Thanks much, regardless!

Answer (score 0):

For fun, the `pstricks` solution, with the `pst-eucl` package:

```
 \documentclass[svgnames, border=6pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{pst-eucl}
 \usepackage{auto-pst-pdf} %% To compile with pdflatex --enablewrite18 (MiKTeX) or pdflatex --shell-escape (TeX Live, MacTeX)

\begin{document}
\psset{linecolor=RoyalBlue, linewidth=1.2pt, plotstyle=curve}
\begin{pspicture}(-5,-3.5)(5,3.5)
\multido{\na=2.4+2.1,\nb=1.6+1.4}{2}{\pstEllipse(0,0)(\na,\nb)%
\multido{\i=0+90}{4}{\pstEllipseRotNode[PointName=none, RotAngle=\i](0,0)(\na,\nb){A\i}}%
}%
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]